# Increase compatibility list for Google Play Store

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-manifest

My published app has support for only 349 devices. I'd very much like to extend that. I realise the minimum sdk version of 16 negates quite a number. Is there anything else I could change in my AndroidManifest that might greatly increase the coverage? It doesn't support the Nexus 5x running Android 6.0.1 for example. I'd very much like to know why. Also is it possible to just update the manifest without updating/versioning the app?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <manifest android:versionName="0.0.11" android:versionCode="114" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" package="com.theexample.example" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="23" android:minSdkVersion="16"/>
    <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <permission android:name="com.theexample.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.theexample.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:supportsRtl="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <activity android:name="com.theexample.example.MainActivity" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushHandlerActivity" android:exported="true"/>
    <receiver android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.BackgroundActionButtonHandler"/>
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
    <category android:name="com.theexample.example"/>
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.GCMIntentService" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
    </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushInstanceIDListenerService" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
    </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.RegistrationIntentService" android:exported="false"/>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:exported="false"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <provider android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="100" android:authorities="com.theexample.example.firebaseinitprovider"/>
    </application>
    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurred as I had inadvertently built the install for x86. I modified the build.gradle file setting ext.cdvBuildMultipleApks = false and rebuilt it.